# MBP shut down and will not power back on

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, charger

My MacBook unexpectedly shutdown and not responding to power button or even battery status button, the lights on battery status isn't showing too. What happened? What should I do?
Edit : the charger light is dim and it's blinking amber and green light.

Comment: By memory status button do you mean the button on the left edge of the Mac with 8 LEDs next to it?

Comment: @Mr Rabbit yes, not sure what is it called

Comment: Ah, ok, those are the battery indicator lights.  Assuming the battery is fully charged you would see all of the lights, with them decreasing as the battery charge decreases.

Comment: @Mr Rabbit the charger lights are amber and green and both are changing after 15-20 sec and dim

Comment: You might try an SMC reset.  The process varies based on the Mac, this article should help you - http://support.apple.com/kb/ht3964

Comment: @Mr Rabbit I tried the link procedure and it didn't work. My MBP won't start

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After searching the net and not coming up with any solution, i went to Apple Care Center and they had it diagnosed, turned out, it was full of dust. They recommended me having it serviced every 6 months. Phew, now its working fine.

Answer (score -4):

We get this all the time, just wiggle it and it will turn red ;)